# Voltage multipliers work worse with more stages?

Tags: simulation, multiplier

I'm simulating voltage multipliers (Dickson topology) with the stages from 1 to 12, following the paper "Design Optimization and Implementation for RF Energy Harvesting Circuits, 2012". The load was fixed at 15 kOhm.

What made me confuse was that, in my simulation results, the output voltage was lower at low Pin (input RF power) when the stage increased, although it was higher with higher Pin. And the power conversion efficiency (PCE = Pdc/Pin x 100%) was decreased. I attached my simulation results for the comparison.

[image]

In the paper I mentioned, they intended to design a system that the output voltage reached 1.8V at Pin = -20 dBm (?). And they got this by parallel connection of 2 circuits, one with 7 stages and one with 10 stages. Their efficiency is higher with more circuits (file attached).

[image]

Here is my results
[image]

Could anyone get the multiplier results the same as that of the paper? I tried using different matching topologies and values, but the results are still the same trend: decreasing with higher stages!

Comment: There are long, drawn-out papers published about variation vs number of sections, etc. It's a well-covered topic, I think. Have you tried to find any of the published discussions? I think I've got Ph.D. Theses, chapters in books, IEEE transactions articles, and gobs of such white papers (files) stored on my machine. Maybe a dozen or more. Not hard to find, really.

Comment: Did you optimize the capacitor ratios? I believe you have multiple interacting capacitive dividers the more stages you add.

Comment: Is there some obvious difference between your circuits and the circuits in the paper?

Comment: The devil's in the detail - show your circuit.

Comment: You are attempting an energy harvesting application, using RF energy to power only one side of the Dickson capacitors, according to the PDF.  The way your curves drop off, your overhead per stage is too great, and your efficiency is too poor. For more info from us, we need more info from you -- please post your actual circuit and operating parameters.